# NPM to existing project?

Tags: npm

I have an online site and Im going to overhaul it. While I cannot find **any** information about if I can use npm and some kind of package manager (*e.g* Webpack) on live site which is on shared host (which has latest Node.js, npm support *etc*), Im going to develope it locally and worry about "publishing" it later on.

**Is there a way to somehow *covert* my current downloaded project to npm project or Im better off just starting a new project?** This is rather confusing, I've never used npm before.

Im using WordPress, everything is run with PHP atm but Im going to overhaul it and use Node.js.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you want to convert a PHP app into a NodeJS app?  I'm pretty sure that's *not* what you want to do, but I can't come up with anything else.

Comment: @chugadie This is my final goal: to have PHP backend for WP and JS front-end app. But Im not sure how I should set it up with npm at the moment. I have downloaded whole current project but Im not sure where does it fit.. Should I just start a new npm project and just start working with front-end and then try to fit my front-end directories and files with my WP theme later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM *can* be used to collect and manage Javascript dependencies for the browser so as to create a stand alone front-end JS app.  BUT, bower is probably a better choice.

NPM is designed to manage Javascript dependencies for projects that use NodeJS or use the CommonJS module format for requiring modules.

Bower is specifically a package manager (like npm or composer) but it is meant to manage browser based javascript dependencies.

Currently, javascript doesn't have a formally defined module/import system, so a number of competing require() functions are been produced.  NodeJS comes with a require() function that searches the npm/ folder for modules.  Browserify is a pre-processor that can scan the npm folder for a dependency and all of its dependencies and bundle them into 1 file for a browser to download  (because browser's don't have a require() function because the JS standard doesn't have define one)

I might be rambling here, but you should probably look at bower, and then - at some point in the future - look at either browserify or requirejs to combine and optimize all the JS plugins for your front-end app.

Edit for clarity:

Basically there are 2 engines to run your JS application: the browser or NodeJS.  NodeJS needs npm, the browser has no idea what npm is.  If you want to write a clean, single page app, all JS front-end for a PHP backend, you don't need NodeJS, and therefore don't need npm.  Using npm will prematurely complicate the development of a front-end browser app because it will force you to decide on a require() implementation (Browserify or Requirejs) right from the start.